# How to access TCP option headers from inside IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, tcp, http-headers, nat

In some circumstances providers of Internet acceleration services (e.g. Akamai's IPA) will do NAT'ing of the connection, but provide information about the original client IP addess in a TCP option, i.e. at the end of the TCP header.

Certain Load Balancers such as BIG-IP are able to convert the information from the TCP header into an HTTP X-Forwarded-For header line, which our applications can read:

https://devcentral.f5.com/Tutorials/TechTips/tabid/63/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/1086447/Accessing-TCP-Options-from-iRules.aspx

But how can I get at the information from an IIS/ASP.NET application, if I am NOT behind one of these load balancers?

I have looked into writing a CHttpModule in C++ for this, and the IHttpContext also exposes a GetConnection() method. But the IHttpConnection interface returned is much too simplistic and does not give access to any low-level info like TCP options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693613(v=vs.90).aspx

Any help, direction, pointers etc. are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this product but it sounds like what you need - http://www.winfrasoft.com/products/X-Forwarded-For/

Claus Rathje

Comment: Hi Claus. This component takes the X-Forwared-For header from HTTP and uses it in the IIS log. What I was looking for was something to take information from the **TCP** header instead.